# jQuery - contains | Why this one doesn't work while other the same works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
    <form action="http://localhost/projekt2/posts" class="posts" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <span class="left-margin-span"><a href="#" id="all">Wszystkie (90)</a> | <a href="#" id="published">Opublikowane (89)</a> | <a href="#" id="planned">Zaplanowane (5)</a>
        </span>
        <div class="top-left-margin">
        <input type="submit" name="delete-checked" value="Usuń zaznaczone"  class="delete-checked" />
<select name="select-date">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Wszystkie Daty</option>
<option value="201705">Maj 2017</option>
<option value="201706">Czerwiec 2017</option>
<option value="201701">Styczeń 2017</option>
<option value="Invalid Date">Invalid Date</option>
</select>
<select name="select-category">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Wszystkie Kategorie</option>
<option value="ale nie no kurde w dupe">ale nie no kurde w dupe</option>
<option value="Informatyka">Informatyka</option>
<option value="Mleczkooooo">Mleczkooooo</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="filter" value="Przefiltruj"  id="filter" />
        Razem 90
        </div>
        <div class="container-wide">
            <div class="title"><span class="container-wide-center-span">Posty</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            <table class="table2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Tytuł
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Kategorie
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Data
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table1">
                                <tr id="row-1">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="1" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Przykładowy Tytuł Strony                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">ale nie no kurde w dupe</a>,                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-05-28                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-3">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc!                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">Informatyka</a>, <a href="#">ale nie no kurde w dupe</a>,                   </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-05-04                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-4">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="4" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Post do kibasy                  </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">Mleczkooooo</a>,                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-06-13                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-5">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="5" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Fajne to co nie                 </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#">ale nie no kurde w dupe</a>,                    </td>
                    <td>
                        2017-01-13                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-64">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="64" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        3                   </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-66">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="66" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        5                   </td>
                    <td>
                                            </td>
                    <td>
                        0000-00-00                  </td>
                </tr>
                            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input#filter').on('click', function(form) {
        form.preventDefault();
        var category = $('select[name="select-category"]').val();
        alert(category);
        $( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' ).css( "font-size", "50px" );
        $( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' ).each(function () {
        // $( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' ).css( "font-size", "50px" );
        // $( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' ).each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == category)
            {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

And look at these two lines:

`$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' ).css( "font-size", "50px" );`

and

`$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' ).each(function () {`

Works perfectly. Whole td that contains word from category var now is 50px font-size.

But second line which is almost the same doesn't work, doesn't remove closest tr.

But they are they select the same element. Look, they are the same:

`$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' )`

So why?

Second works for me when I add "a" to it, so it looks like:

`$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td a:contains("' + category + '")' )`

And it works... But why not earlier?

First one works perfectly without "a", so why second one doesn't? Should work as well too as first one that do font-size bigger

Comment: I can't find the input#filter or the select with name select-category in your html, please include all relevant code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen eddited

Comment: In your code it says `name="filter"`. It must be `id="filter"`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vtq19z96/ I modified your code a bit. Click on your button and take a look at the console output. `if ($(this).text() == category)` is never true.

Comment: It is about `$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' )` Why in second line has to be in addition "a" so it is `$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td a:contains("' + category + '")' )`

Comment: For me it does not work by adding `a:contains()`. Moreover there is no `a` tag within the `td`.

Comment: but it works after add this "a", and there is, look for example td `<td>
                        <a href="#">Mleczkooooo</a>,                    </td>
                    <td>` @zuluk

Comment: So, I have changed the code: https://jsfiddle.net/vtq19z96/2/ But it does not make sense :-). You have to describe what the expected result is when the selected value from selectbox category matches the category text in the table.

Comment: Thank you @zuluk. You helped me somehow :).

Comment: You are welcome. Glad that you found a solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I collect the key points of my answer here.

```
$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:contains("' + category + '")' )
```

will be not so efficient because all table cells will be used. It will be better just to check the relevant cells, in your case column 3:

```
$( 'table.table1 tbody tr td:nth-of-type(3):contains("' + category + '")' ).each(function () {
```

Current fiddle with shortened code: https://jsfiddle.net/vtq19z96/3/